# IndexOutOfBoundsError while coding a Game in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I ran into a IndexOutOfBound error while coding a school project. This problem isn't stable, this problem seems to occur very random...

```
public void run(){ // Main game methode 
    Image Background = this.images.get(0);//get background because we can
    Player Player1 = this.players.get(0);//get player 1
    Player Player2 = this.players.get(1);//get player 2

    Player1.setHorSp(1);//give start speed to player 1
    Player2.setHorSp(1);//give start speed to player 2
    while(this.running == true && this.crash == false){ // main game loop, loops when game is started and there is no crash
        // Player 1
        if(this.turnable == 0 && Player1.getDir() > 0){
            Player1.setPrevLine(Player1.getCurrentLine());//safe previous line for testing
            if(Player1.getDir() == 1){ //check which key and horizontal speed so it can't move in opposite direction
                if(Player1.getHorSp() == -1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY()-Player1.getWidth()+Player1.getHeight());
                }
                if(Player1.getHorSp() == 1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+Player1.getWidth()-grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX()-Player1.getHeight()+Player1.getWidth());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-Player1.getWidth());
                }
                Player1.setLineNr(Player1.getLineNr()+1); //tell player that it had turned
                Player1.setImage("BikeBlueUp.png"); //change image in the right direction
                Player1.setWidth(grid); //correct images size
                Player1.setHeight(2*grid);
                Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2);//set point line is atteched to bibe
                Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                Player1.setHorSp(0); //give speed in the right direction
                Player1.setVerSp(-1);
            }
            if(Player1.getDir() == 2){ //check which key and if is in grid
                if(Player1.getVerSp() == -1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY());
                }
                if(Player1.getVerSp() == 1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-Player1.getWidth());
                }
                Player1.setLineNr(Player1.getLineNr()+1); //tell player that it had turned
                Player1.setImage("BikeBlueRight.png"); //change image in the right direction
                Player1.setWidth(2*grid); //correct images size
                Player1.setHeight(grid);
                Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+Player1.getWidth()-grid/2);//set point line is atteched to bibe
                Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                Player1.setHorSp(1); //give speed in the right direction
                Player1.setVerSp(0);
            }
            if(Player1.getDir() == 3){ //check which key and horizontal speed so it can't move in opposite direction
                if(Player1.getHorSp() == -1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY());
                }
                if(Player1.getHorSp() == 1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+Player1.getWidth()-grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX()-Player1.getHeight()+Player1.getWidth());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY());
                }
                Player1.setLineNr(Player1.getLineNr()+1); //tell player that it had turned
                Player1.setImage("BikeBlueDown.png"); //change image in the right direction
                Player1.setWidth(grid); //correct images size
                Player1.setHeight(2*grid);
                Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2);//set point line is atteched to bibe
                Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-grid/2);
                Player1.setHorSp(0); //give speed in the right direction
                Player1.setVerSp(1);
            }
            if(Player1.getDir() == 4){ //check which key and horizontal speed so it can't move in opposite direction
                if(Player1.getVerSp() == -1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX()-Player1.getHeight()+Player1.getWidth());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY());
                }
                if(Player1.getVerSp() == 1){
                    Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2); //set end of line
                    Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-grid/2);
                    addLine(Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Player1.getLineX(),Player1.getLineY(),Color.BLUE);//make next line
                    Player1.setCurrentLine(Player1.getLineNr()+Player2.getLineNr());//use next line
                    Player1.setX(Player1.getX()-Player1.getHeight()+Player1.getWidth());
                    Player1.setY(Player1.getY()+Player1.getHeight()-Player1.getWidth());
                }
                Player1.setLineNr(Player1.getLineNr()+1); //tell player that it had turned
                Player1.setImage("BikeBlueLeft.png"); //change image in the right direction
                Player1.setWidth(2*grid); //correct images size
                Player1.setHeight(grid);
                Player1.setLineX(Player1.getX()+grid/2);//set point line is atteched to bibe
                Player1.setLineY(Player1.getY()+grid/2);
                Player1.setHorSp(-1); //give speed in the right direction
                Player1.setVerSp(0);
            }
        }
```

this generates the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at Game.run(Game.java:388)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

still this error now occured while pressing the up button. This error didn't occur for the other 2 times and then out of nowwere it happens.

this error was generated after pressing the right button

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 11
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at Game.run(Game.java:388)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

this error was generated after pressing the right button, and it worked, in the same game, for 1 time earlier... And even after 3 day's of debugging we still can't see a patron.

*Has anyone ever seen this before and if so: how do we fix it?*

--JYT

Ps. the whole code is here http://pastebin.com/0wvyr3qh

Comment: You are trying to access the 6th element of an array list with only 5 elements.

Comment: What is the content on line no 388? It probably is handling user input, and hence is null at times.

Comment: which line of your code is line #388 ?

Comment: Ya, somewhere you've got an off-by-one issue.  I can't see it in the code but I don't know what line is #388 based on the post.  Remember that the 5th element of an array is at address 4, not 5.

Comment: Line CurrentLineP2 = this.lines.get(Player2.getCurrentLine()); // line 388

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you try to do, but the error occures because:
`Player2.getCurrentLine()` returns the value of `this.lines.size()`,
so you try to access a **non-existing** object in a list **(if a list is of size 5, it has objects 0-4)**.

If your grid is cyclic, you can use:

```
Line CurrentLineP2 = this.lines.get(Player2.getCurrentLine() % this.lines.size());
```

instead of:

```
Line CurrentLineP2 = this.lines.get(Player2.getCurrentLine());
```

If its not cyclic, you need to handle this case. How can a player be at a line that does not exists?

At any case, adding **all** relevant code will help us help you.